# How do I split a PHP form into two sections to be sent separately using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

This is what I have so far using jQuery:

```
var url = "my-path-to-url";

$("button.btn-book").on("click", function(e, response){

    e.preventDefault();

    $.post(url, {
        "your-name": $("input[name='your-name']").val(),
        "email": $("input[name='email']").val(),
        "phone": $("input[name='phone']").val().replace(/\s/g, ''),
        "initial_form": "true"
    }, function(response){

        if(response == "sent"){

            $(".form-submit").on("click", function(){

                $.post(url, {
                    "treatment": $("input[name='treatment']").val(),
                    "method": $("input[name='method']").val(),
                    "long_form": "true"
                });

            });
        }

        if(response == "fail"){

            alert("Please make sure all fields are filled in.");


        }

    });

});
```

I'm trying to set it so when the user fills out the first part of the form, i.e. the first 3 fields, it sends an email so if they opt out, it grabs the important details.

The second part of the form is just ticking radio buttons and if the user fills these out, the form sends another email but with all the information - (The text fields + the radio button fields).

What I think I'm stuck on is joining these two elements so it does something like this: "If only the first 3 fields are filled out, grab these values and send it to the url with the form script.

If all fields are filled out, grab all the data and send it to the url with the form script.

Hope it makes sense, thanks.

Tom's asked me to paste my form HTML:

```
        <form class="booking-form" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" id="booking-form">

        <input name="booking-form" value="true" type="hidden">

        <div class='booking-progress'>
            <label class='active'>Step 1</label>
            <label>Step 2</label>
            <label>Step 3</label>
            <label>Done</label>
        </div>

        <h1><?php the_title() ?></h1>

        <h2>We look forward to helping you at this complimentary consultation</h2>

        <div class="booking-form-container">
            <div class="cycle-slideshow" data-cycle-fx=scrollHorz data-cycle-timeout=0 data-cycle-slides="> div" data-cycle-next=".cycle-next" data-cycle-allow-wrap="false">   
                <div class="personal-details">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="your-name" id="your-name" placeholder="Name &#42;" required data-min-length="3" data-error='This field is required'>
                        <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email &#42;" required data-minlength="7" data-error='This field is required, and must be at least 7 characters'>
                        <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="phone" id="phone" placeholder="Phone &#42;" required data-minlength="6" data-error='This field is required, and must be at least 6 digits'>
                        <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                    </div>

                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-book cycle-next">Go!</button>
                </div>

                <div class="treatment-details">

                    <h3>Select your Treatment</h3>

                    <div class="radio">
                        <input type="radio" name="treatment" class="next-arrow" value="General Patient" id="general-patient">
                        <label class="cycle-next" for="general-patient">General Patient</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="radio">
                        <input type="radio" name="treatment" class="next-arrow" value="Dental Implants" id="dental-implants">
                        <label class="cycle-next" for="dental-implants">Dental Implants</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="radio">
                        <input type="radio" name="treatment" class="next-arrow" value="Teeth Whitening" id="teeth-whitening">
                        <label class="cycle-next" for="teeth-whitening">Teeth Whitening</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="radio">
                        <input type="radio" name="treatment" class="next-arrow" value="Teeth Straightening" id="teeth-straightening">
                        <label class="cycle-next" for="teeth-straightening">Teeth Straightening</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="radio">
                        <input type="radio" name="treatment" class="next-arrow" value="Facial Aesthetics" id="facial-aesthetics">
                        <label class="cycle-next" for="facial-aesthetics">Facial Aesthetics</label>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="contact-method">

                    <h3>Best method of contact?</h3>

                    <div class="radio">
                        <input type="radio" name="method" class="phone-icon form-submit" value="Phone" id="by-phone">
                        <label class="cycle-next" for="by-phone">By Phone</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="radio">
                        <input type="radio" name="method" class="mail-icon form-submit" value="Email" id="by-email">
                        <label class="cycle-next" for="by-email">By Email</label>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="thanks-message">
                    <h3>All done</h3>
                    <p>Thank you, we will contact you soon.</p>
                </div>
            </div>  
        </div>          

    </form>
```

Comment: Can you post the html of the form so we can get a clearer meaning of what your trying to achieve

Comment: Post complete flow what do you want ? and to whom email will be send after submitting first step and after second step ?

Answer (score 0):

It is just an idea, but why don't you simply send all your fields in your PHP file.
Test if one of your fields (number 3+) is empty, "do this", else "do that".

Put some JS validation on your form to avoid sending empty data.

Comment: Hmm, that makes sense but the form does not have a final submit button if that makes sense. The form starts with the first 3 fields and the button that displays the next section of the form, sends an email with the information of the first 3 fields - so if the user decides that they don't want to fill in the rest, the first 3 fields are sent regardless. The idea is after the short form has been sent, if the user continues to fill out the rest, it sends another email containing the first 3 fields plus the extra fields. See what I mean? Would the method you described be able to do this?

Comment: I should add that the first button mentioned above, sends the short form and the last radio button sends the long form. Hope this helps.

Comment: My suggestion should do the trick. You can use JQuery to check how many fields are filled out, then call a function, or an other one. You should try to find a solution where only one email is send, because if you recieve two emails, the first will be useless.

Comment: I see what you mean but the form isn't a standard one where you can see all the fields. I should have mentioned above, that after you select a button or an option, it slides to the next section so there is no way the user can see the whole form - would this be an issue? I can't see how the form would know if the user is going to fill out part or all of the form. I'm really stuck on this, haha.